# Assignment Delay

Tags: verilog

What is the difference between the following two statements in Verilog?

```
#5 a = b;
a = #5 b;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first case the whole assignment is delayed by 5 'time units'.

In the second case value of b is read but the assignment is delayed by 5 'time units'.

The difference is if b changes in the 'next' 5 time units.
 - In the first case the new, (changed) value of b gets assigned.
 - In the second case the old value of b is assigned.